# Fetching and filtering relations in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have the following models in Eloquent: groups, threads, comments and users. I want to find all comments in a specific group from a specific user.

This is my current approach:

```
$group->threads->each(function ($thread) use ($user_id)
{
  $user_comments = $thread->comments->filter(function ($comment) use ($user_id)
  {
    return $comment->owner_id == $id;
  });
});
```

This looks ugly as hell, is probably slow as hell, and I just want to get rid of it. What is the fastest and most elegant way in Eloquent to get to my result set?

Comment: Do you want to get all comments combined or on a thread by thread basis?

Comment: I don’t really care. All comments combined are sufficient.

Comment: How do you relations looks like ? Because if you had setup your relations properly you could do something like $group->find(1)->users()>find(1)->comments;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[patricus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28439826/133166) solution pointed me in the right direction. I cross posted my question to the [laracasts Forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fetching-and-filtering-relations-in-laravel-eloquent) and got a lot of help from [Jarek Tkaczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/jarek-tkaczyk) who also frequently visits this site.

`hasManyThrough()` for the `Group` model is the way to go:

```
public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('ThreadComment', 'Thread');
}
```

There a couple of caveats, though:

1. Use the relation object instead of a collection (`$group->comments()`, **NOT** `$group->comments`)
2. If you use Laravel’s soft deletes you can’t just change the `get()` to a `delete()`, because you’ll get an ambiguity error for the column `updated_at`. You can’t prefix it either, it’s just how Eloquent works.

If you want to delete all comments from a specific user in a specific group you’ll have to do it a little bit differently:

```
$commentsToDelete = $group->comments()
        ->where('threads_comments.owner_id', $id)
        ->select('threads_comments.id')
        ->lists('id');

ThreadComment::whereIn('id', $commentsToDelete)->delete();
```

You basically fetch all relevant IDs in the first query and then batch delete them in a second one.

Comment: Making the difference between relation object () and collection, is just the answer to most realtionship issues. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

If a `group` hasMany `threads`, and a `thread` hasMany `comments`, you can add another relationship to group: `group` hasMany `comments` through `threads`.

On the group:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Comment', 'Thread');
}
```

Now, you can get the comments in a group by `$group->comments;`

From here, you can tack on the requirement for the user:

```
$user_comments = $group->comments()->where('owner_id', $user_id)->get();
```

If you want, you can extract the where out into a scope on the Comment.

Comment: Does this work with scope? say `$group->comments()->pinned()->get()`

Comment: @deymbwoi Yeah, it's a normal relationship so it should work fine.